# Convert a fraction to a decimal in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to type a fraction into a cell in Google Sheets and have it convert to a decimal (like Excel does by default)

For example, if I enter "181 7/8" I would like to convert to "181.875" when I hit enter.

I cannot find anything about this on the webs. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

`=181+7/8`

and it will be converted automatically to 181.875

Comment: I also needed to use this format in order to do arithmetic with some measurements I took, thank you!